# How to get winform fullpath?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a winform and its fullpath is C:\test.exe

How do I get the winform fullpath at run time? For example, the user may move the winform to other places. Thanks.

Comment: This is the answer: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName`

Answer (score 2):

As you are using WinForms, there are two simple properties to choose from on the `Application` class:

- [`Application.StartupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) will get you the directory in which the application started.
- [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) will get you the full path to the application (including the filename).

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the file name:
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.Name

For folder name, try:
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location (not sure... on top of my head)

Comment: I want fullpath ie including drive and folder (if any) information

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) ().CodeBase (or Location) from a Windows-Form application (but not from ASP.NET applications).

Answer (score 0):

This information is part of the My namespace.  The directory path can be found via
[My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6whasz3x%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` 
It will get you the fully qualified path of working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should be prompted to add a reference to System.Reflection, but this should give you exactly what you want:

```
  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```